# Can we bind old records to a new Record Type automatically?

Tags: record-type, record

E. g., in some object we haven't any Record Type yet. But we decide to create it and want to bind all old records of this object, that haven't Record Type, automatically. Is it possible? Or we have to do this through Apex only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to bind old records to the new recordtype then extract the old recordIds and update the recordtypeId through dataloader or workbench.

Otherwise, write a script in apex to update the recordtypeIds

Comment: Realfire support dml statements. In this case you can issue (update object1 set recordtypeid = 'your record type id' where recordtypeid = null). Or you could also use standard dataloader and workbench if you have couple of records to update. [Disclaimer: I'm part of the team that builds Realfire]